# how to change matplotlib default figure location on screen

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm on MacOSX, with two monitors using matplotlib.  I like to have my terminals on my main screen and a web browser or plots I'm making on the secondary monitor.  When using matplotlib or in ipython --pylab, whenever I make a new figure it shows up behind my terminals on my main monitor.  It'd be nice if I could change the default so new plots always appear somewhere on my second monitor.

**How can I change the default on screen figure location in matplotlib?**

Comment: Close, I was hoping for a solution I could set in an rc file somewhere.  In the link you posted one would have to set this parameter in every script / at the beginning of every sesssion.  Although this is fine in the meantime.

Comment: can you just add the setting to your `matplotlibrc` file?

Comment: Oh.. Yup looks like I can.  Thanks @ChristopherPearson